# Using PWM with RPi.GPIO in Python

Tags: gpio, python, pi-2, rpi.gpio, python-3

**Scenario:** I want to control a PC fan using the Raspberry Pi. The 4-wire-fan (MGT9212UR-W25) has its own power supply (12V) and can be controled via PWM. I would like to control it with a Python script using the `RPi.GPIO` module, which unfortunately leads to bad results with a loud creaking noise. The fan's PWM input is connected to the Raspberry Pi on pin 12 (BCM). I would like to set the speed to 20% (for this example).

**Good results:** GPIO command line utility

```
gpio -g mode 12 pwm
gpio pwmr 100
gpio -g pwm 12 20
```

**Bad results:** RPi.GPIO module using Python 3.5

```
from RPi import GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
pwm = GPIO.PWM(12, 50)
pwm.start(0)
pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(20)
```

**Question:** Both attemps work, but the command line utility always leads to smooth results (`pwmr` not required), while the Python script leaves me with a crackling fan (loud). I tried different values for ChangeDutyCycle and ChangeFrequency, so what am I doing wrong? How can the good results (from the command line utility) be produced using RPi.GPIO in Python? Thanks!!

Comment: I suggest you try gpiozero See https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating_from_rpigpio.html?highlight=pwm#pwm-pulse-width-modulation AFAIK this still uses software PWM but you can vary frequency https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_output.html?highlight=pwm#pwmoutputdevice

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I tried gpiozero, which gives better results than RPi.GPIO, but using pigpio runs the fan even smoother.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably found an answer thanks to @joan 's answer.

It seems like `RPi.PWM` can only do software PWM, but the fan requires hardware PWM to run as smooth as possible. To do hardware PWM on any GPIO pin, the **pigpio** daemon has to be executed, and controlled by Python. Therefore, [pigpio](https://github.com/guymcswain/pigpio-client/wiki/Install-and-configure-pigpiod) has to be installed first and configured to be started on boot (`systemd`). After that, hardware PWM is available on BCM pin 12 at 20% duty cycle at a frequency of 40 kHz with the following Python script:

```
import pigpio
PI = pigpio.pi()
PI.hardware_PWM(12, 40000, 200000)
```

I don't know if 40 kHz is the right value, but it works.

Comment: In fact using PWM to control a fan is poor practice. If the PWM is fast enough or the inertia high enough it may work - depending on what kind of motor.

Comment: @Milliways The fan is a 12V [4-wire](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/0726R-5UPMSFCNcFSHzteaYDwzqKs2lYk84Wzgq2u_EkhhrIY-kQURGpD746KBfZY_aSoI9_zn-7czGMFCILvKgSzydOwt1hfYerQ8n2BOt__nwTfhewN6YVaQCYvXtbvKBPCPJcIHlgZ25gESzf5G7lvq_DWhseWX4zT1WHoLo). Since one line is PWM control, I think the fan expects to be controlled with PWM.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 1):

There are two fundamental differences between the two approaches.

The gpio utility (part of wiringPi)

- is using hardware timed PWM.
- appears to be setting a frequency of 40 kHz.

The RPi.GPIO script

- is using software timed PWM.
- is setting a frequency of 50 Hz.

I'd guess the frequency is the main factor.